# implicit pointer conversion of array doesn't appear to point to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operating-system

[link to full code](https://gist.github.com/gwoplock/44e6bb1484b6d66bbb3e9857de66a819)

I am working on writing an operating system and as part, I need to tell the CPU about segments in memory. The basic idea is that I load the GDT register with the LGDT assembly call. The parameter to that is the memory address of a structure containing the size and location of the actual GDT. The problem I have is that on line 75 of GlobalDescriptorTable.h I set the address of the array in my structure to be passed to LGDT but when I inspect the memory at the address given by the structure there is nothing there.

```
class GlobalDescriptorTable {
private:
    GdtEntry _gdt[256];
    size_t size;
    GdtDescriptor gdtd;
public:
    GlobalDescriptorTable( ) ;
    GdtEntry encodeGlobalDescriptorTableEntry(uint32_t limit,
            uint32_t baseAddress, Access access, Flags flags);
    void load( ) {
        //get size, -1 because Int-hell hates you
        size_t sizeOfGdt = (3 * sizeof(GdtEntry)) - 1;
        //get the info to tell cpu about the GDT

        gdtd.size = (uint16_t)sizeOfGdt;
        gdtd.location = _gdt;
        asm ("LGDT %[gdtd]" : : [gdtd] "m" (gdtd));
    }
};
```

assignment as a test:

```
uint64_t temp = 0xF00FB00BEE00F0AA;
_gdt[0] = *((GdtEntry*) &temp);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

The `LGDT` instruction wants a linear address, and not a segment-relative address.  This is a different address than you'll get within a C++ program.  Consult the Intel documentation on this instruction for more information.

Comment: looking at the [osdev wiki page](http://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table#Structure) for the GDT it says that paging applies so c++ would give the correct address right?

Comment: It goes thru paging, but does _not_ go thru the segment (CS, DS, etc) registers.  The C++ environment does.

Comment: I've already set up paging when I do this, and this would be what sets up the segments. I don't believe that is the issue.